# Gentiles and Kibbud Av V'im

Tags: gentiles, kibbud-av-veim-honoring

I wondered if anyone knew the reason that kibbud av v'im is not one of the Noachide laws? Seems like a pretty universal ethic that should be applied to everyone. Why isn't it? Does anyone know any sources on this?

Comment: Why this one more than "love your neighbor" or "return lost objects" or any other?

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Ben and thanks for this first question. Can I recommend you take the [tour](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour) to get a sense of how the site works?  Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: IMHO, the idea of "commandments" is very vague both for the Jews and Gentiles. Just as we have thousands of right and wrong "conducts" beyond the 613 Mitzvot, same with the Gentiles. The Gemora in Kiddushin tries to deal with this question - to what extent are they commanded on Kibbud but it is unanimously accepted that they are rewarded. Also they don't have positive commandments in general, just don'ts.